# How to use OR within (negative) Bash conditions

Tags: bash, if-statement, user-input

This section of my script checks whether the distro is either Ubuntu or Arch. The problem is that I cannot figure out what to replace the **OR** with to make it work. I tried `-o` and other suggestions from various websites without succes.

```
if [ ! $(lsb_release -is) == "Ubuntu" OR "Arch" ]; then
 echo "Neither Ubuntu nor Arch!"
 read -p "Continue anyway(y/N)? "
 sleep 0
 [ "$REPLY" == "y" ] || exit
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
rel="$(lsb_release -is)"
if [[ "${rel}" != "Ubuntu" && "${rel}" != "Arch" ]]; then
   # Neither Ubuntu nor Arch
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `case/esac` construct

```
case $(lsb_release -is) in
  Ubuntu|Arch ) echo "Ubuntu or Arch found";;
  * ) 
 echo "Neither Ubuntu nor Arch!"
 read -p "Continue anyway(y/N)? "
 sleep 0
 [ "$REPLY" == "y" ] || exit
 ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

Closest to your original code would be:

```
if [[ ! $(lsb_release -is) =~ Ubuntu|Arch ]]; then 
    echo "Neither Ubuntu nor Arch!"
    read -p "Continue anyway(y/N)? "
    sleep 0
    [ "$REPLY" == "y" ] || exit; 
fi
```

This uses the match operator introduced in bash 3. Also note that the above is valid in bash 3.2, prior to that you need to use quotes for the pattern.

if you don't have bash 3 you can use grep

```
if ! lsb_release -is| egrep -q 'Ubuntu|Arch'; then 
    echo "Neither Ubuntu nor Arch!"
    read -p "Continue anyway(y/N)? "
    sleep 0
    [ "$REPLY" == "y" ] || exit; 
fi
```

Note that -q is a non-standard option of grep

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, here is a slightly longer but more flexible way of achieving the same result.

```
rel="$(lsb_release -is)"
if [[ "${rel}" = "Arch" ]]; then
    echo "It's Arch"
  elif [[ "${rel}" = "Ubuntu" ]]; then
    echo "It's Ubuntu"
  else
    echo "It's Neither"
    read -p "Continue anyway(y/N)? "
    sleep 0
    [ "$REPLY" == "y" ] || exit
fi
```

Comment: Here, too, you want to use `case`.